How to compare two lists and only get the index of the first difference
I have a list and I need to update values ​​in it.
These updates are based on calculations, so with each iteration the values ​​may change, but with each iteration the beginning of the list remains the same, only the last items changing.
To save processing time, I want to start each iteration from the first difference only.
Sample:
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        List<string> updatedList = new List<string>();

        list[0] = "A";
        updatedList[0] = "A";

        list[1] = "B";
        updatedList[1] = "B";

        list[2] = "C";
        updatedList[2] = "C";

        list[3] = "D";
        updatedList[3] = "E";

I want to get index 3 for this sample.

You can use LINQ's Zip, Select, and FirstOrDefault operators:
int? index =
    list
    .Zip(updatedList, (item, updated) => (item, updated))
    .Select((pair, index) => (pair, index))
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.pair.item != x.pair.updated)
    ?.index;

Not the most performant way, but in case it's fast enough, it will do the trick.

thanks! It was a very quick solution, less than 2 milliseconds. The number of items in the list does not exceed 500.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        List<string> updatedList = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "E" };

        int firstDifferenceIndex = FindFirstDifferenceIndex(list, updatedList);

        Console.WriteLine("Index of the first difference: " + firstDifferenceIndex);
    }

    static int FindFirstDifferenceIndex(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count && i < list2.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list1[i] != list2[i])
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return Math.Min(list1.Count, list2.Count);
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

// with the data from your entry post

int i, diffIndex; i = diffIndex = -1;
list.FirstOrDefault(el => updatedList.Count > ++i
                       && !Equals(el, updatedList[i]) 
                       && (diffIndex = i) > -1);

// diffIndex is now 3 

